# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/api/v1/movies' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

```
package dev.catacoman.movies;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/movies")


public class MovieController {
    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;
    
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getAllMovies()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(movieService.allMovies(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{imdbId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Movie>> getSingleMovie(@PathVariable String imdbId)
    {
    return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Movie>>(movieService.singleMovie(imdbId),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

This is my movie controller in spring. While trying to call this API in front using angular, I get the error from the title:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/api/v1/movies' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

I tried almost everything but didn't find any fix.

I tried adding `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` in multiple ways.
I tried adding a Chrome Extension that remove the CORS Policy thing, still didn't work.
I tried calling another API on my front, a public API, that thing worked so I guess its not my front that has the problem.

Comment: The problem is on the client side, and the error message tells you everything you need to know. Instead of `fetch('localhost:8080/api/v1/movies', ...`, write `fetch(http://localhost:8080/api/v1/movies', ...`.

Comment: are you using Spring Security ?

Comment: Is the issue on backend and not on frontend, right? Do you have a Spring Security configuration?